# Changing bluetooth class to act as a hands free device and car audio

Tags: debian, bluetooth, bluez

I posted this on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com with no luck, figured it is more of a generic linux question than Raspberry pi specific.

I have been using this tool to quickly configure my Pi2 as a bluetooth audio link to my camper van, it works brilliantly.

My question is regarding changing the class of the bluetooth device so it can receive phone call audio too like a normal car hands free kit.

I will admit I am not 100% familiar with all the terminology involved so will apologise in advance.

If I change the class value in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf and reboot I get a different class listed in the bluetoothctl tool output. To get the class I used this tool https://www.ampedrftech.com/cod.htm

When I make the change I think the system is correcting the Class to be Rendering (Speaker) and Capturing (Microphone) Device but I do not see the phone audio option on my phone (See screenshot).

/etc/bluetooth/main.conf

```
[General]

# Default adapter name
# Defaults to 'BlueZ X.YZ'
#Name = BlueZ

# Default device class. Only the major and minor device class bits are
Name = Orion Audio Link
# considered. Defaults to '0x000000'.
#Class = 0x000100
Class = 0x600420
```

This is the output from bluetoothctl

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/bluetooth $ sudo bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13 Orion Audio Link [default]
[NEW] Device 54:B1:21:94:3C:26 deans
[bluetooth]# show
Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13
    Name: Orion Audio Link
    Alias: Orion Audio Link
    Class: 0x0c0420
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: yes
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d052B
    Discovering: no
```

Screenshot from my phone:

[image]